# Multilingual Issues

Tags: i18n-l10n

My website have two languages are french, Japanese and default English.

Have 100 of pages but all pages(English, French & Japanese). But all page view source showing below tags

link href="http://www.mywebsitename.com/ja/node/565323" hreflang="ja"

How to remove this?

Also setup the block region & render language in template page.

English & French both text are coming fine, but French url come with english url, not come in french url.

How to rid this issue?